# How to solve simultaneous non-linear equations with exponential functions?

Tags: c, static-libraries, simultaneous, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

I have a system of equations to solve for `x1` and `x2`:

```
2*erf(A*x2)*exp(B*x1^2+C*x2^2)-D*erf(x1)=0

2*erf(D*x2)*exp(E*x1^2+F*x2^2)-G*erf(x1)-erf(H*x2)*exp(I*x1^2)=0
```

where `B` and `C` are negative while rest of the constants are positive.

I tried to solve it in C using multiroot function from the GSL library. It seems that multiroot was not able to solve the system. I tried the same implementation of multiroot for non-linear simultaneous polynomial functions (no exponential part in it) and it worked well and gave correct results. 
Any suggestions on how to solve such a system? Or any other powerful library which can be used for such equations?

Answer (score 0):

Look for a numerical method, for example the ["Numerical recipes"](http://www.nr.com) book is higly regarded. Solving nonalgebraic equations is a vast, complex area. Systems of such equations doubly so.